# Why is the Windows Forms UI blocked when executing Task with ContinueWith?

Tags: c#, winforms, task-parallel-library, blocked, continuewith

I spent a couple of days searching in Google and trying to understand why in my case Windows Forms **UI is blocked** when executing pings in **Tasks**.
I saw a lot of similar cases, but none of them explains my specific case.

#### Issue description:

I have an application which sends pings asynchronously. Each ping is send inside of a Task. I use `.ContinueWith` to receive result of a ping and print it to textbox without blocking UI thread. **It works OK if I launch all pings once.** If I add a `while {run}` loop to make them run forever my UI becomes unresponsive and blocked, and none of the results are printed to the textbox.

**Problematic Code:**

```
Action action2 = () => {
        for (int i = 0; i < ipquantity; i++)
        {
            int temp1 = i;
            string ip = listView1.Items[temp1].SubItems[1].Text;

            if (finished[temp1] == true) // Variable helps to check if ping reply was received and printed
                continutask[temp1] = Task<string>.Run(() => PingStart(ip, temp1)).ContinueWith(antecedent => PrintResult(antecedent.Result, temp1));
        }
};

while (run)
{
    action2();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

#### Questions:

1. Why is the UI blocked with a `while` loop and why is it not blocked without it?
2. How can I modify my code to be still able to use Tasks for pings without blocking the UI?
3. Is there a better way to launch endless pings to several IP addresses simultaneously?

#### Complete code:

```
private async void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    run = true;

    int count = listView1.Items.Count;
    task = new Task<string>[count];
    result1 = new string[count];
    finished = new bool[count];
    continutask = new Task[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        finished[i] = true;
    }

        Action action2 = () =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            int temp1 = i;
            string ip = listView1.Items[temp1].SubItems[1].Text;


            if (finished[temp1] == true)
                continutask[temp1] = Task<string>.Run(() => PingStart(ip, temp1)).ContinueWith(antecedent => PrintResult(antecedent.Result, temp1));

        }
    };
    while (run)
    {
        action2();
        //await Task.Delay;
        //Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}

public void PrintResult(string message, int seqnum)
{
    Action action = () =>
    {
        textBox1.AppendText(message);
        textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        textBox1.AppendText("");
        textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    };
    if (InvokeRequired)
        Invoke(action);
    else
        action();
    finished[seqnum] = true;
}

public string PingStart(string ip, int seqnum)
{
    finished[seqnum] = false;

    Ping isPing = new Ping();
    PingReply reply;
    const int timeout = 2000;
    const string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    PingOptions options = new PingOptions();
    // Use the default Ttl value which is 128,
    options.DontFragment = false;

    reply = isPing.Send(ip, timeout, buffer, options);
    string rtt = (reply.RoundtripTime.ToString());

    string success = "N/A";

    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        success = $"{ip}" + " Success!" + $" rtt: [{rtt}]" + $"Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode()} Is pool thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread}";
    }
    else if (reply.Status != IPStatus.Success)
    {
        success = $"{ip}" + $" Not Successful! Status: {reply.Status}" + $"Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode()} Is pool thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread}";
    }

    return success;
}
```

Comment: If you use `await Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep` it shouldn't block. (Or just await the Tasks you run, the while loop seems a bit unnecessary). There reason it blocks completely might be because your Tasks won't run at all while the Thread sleeps. If some of your code can't be run async, you might want to consider using a separate Thread altogether.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would you be so kind to provide the correct syntax of `await Task.Delay` for my case? I have no idea how to use it and to which part of the code to insert it.

Comment: It's quite straight forward. Replace `Thread.Sleep` with `await Task.Delay` (and mark your method async if you haven't already. I'd give you more details but I have no idea what your other methods look like. If you could rewrite your code as a [mcve], you might get better answers.

Comment: I tried and Visual Studio gives me an error: "Cannot await method group".

Comment: You still need the parameters of course. Judging by the error you just wrote `await Task.Delay;` instead of `await Task.Delay(insert time to wait here);`.

Comment: I added code with more details. Does it help?

Comment: Looks complete, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already create (and save) your tasks, the easiest fix would be to await them for each iteration of your while loop:

```
while (run)
{
    action2();

    foreach (Task t in continutask)
        await t;
}
```

That way, when all pings completed (successful or not) you start the entire process again - without delay.

One more thing: You could add a `textBox1.ScrollToEnd();` to `PrintResult`

---

Since there is a lot of room for improvement, below is a rewritten and simplified example. I've removed a lot of unused variables (e.g. `seqnum`) and made the `PingStart` method completely asynchronous. I also replaced your ListBox with a TextBox for easier testing, so you might want to revert that in your code.

This still isn't the *cleanest* of all possible implementations (mainly because of the global `run`) but it should show you how to do things *"more async"* :)

```
private async void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // If the ping loops are already running, don't start them again
    if (run)
        return;

    run = true;

    // Get all IPs (in my case from a TextBox instead of a ListBox
    string[] ips = txtIPs.Text.Split(new[] {"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    // Create an array to store all Tasks
    Task[] pingTasks = new Task[ips.Length];

    // Loop through all IPs
    for(int i = 0; i < ips.Length; i++)
    {
        string ip = ips[i];

        // Launch and store a task for each IP
        pingTasks[i] = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                // while run is true, ping over and over again
                while (run)
                {
                    // Ping IP and wait for result (instead of storing it an a global array)
                    var result = await PingStart(ip);

                    // Print the result (here I removed seqnum)
                    PrintResult(result.Item2);

                    // This line is optional. 
                    // If you want to blast pings without delay, 
                    // you can remove it
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                }
            }
        );
    }

    // Wait for all loops to end after setting run = false.
    // You could add a mechanism to call isPing.SendAsyncCancel() instead of waiting after setting run = false
    foreach (Task pingTask in pingTasks)
        await pingTask;
}

// (very) simplified explanation of changes:
// async = this method is async (and therefore awaitable)
// Task<> = This async method returns a result of type ...
// Tuple<bool, string> = A generic combination of a bool and a string
// (-)int seqnum = wasn't used so I removed it
private async Task<Tuple<bool, string>> PingStart(string ip)
{
    Ping isPing = new Ping();
    const int timeout = 2000;
    const string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    PingOptions options = new PingOptions {DontFragment = false};

    // await SendPingAsync = Ping and wait without blocking
    PingReply reply = await isPing.SendPingAsync(ip, timeout, buffer, options);
    string rtt = reply.RoundtripTime.ToString();

    bool success = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
    string text;

    if (success)
    {
        text = $"{ip}" + " Success!" + $" rtt: [{rtt}]" + $"Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode()} Is pool thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread}";
    }
    else
    {
        text = $"{ip}" + $" Not Successful! Status: {reply.Status}" + $"Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode()} Is pool thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread}";
    }

    // return if the ping was successful and the status message
    return new Tuple<bool, string>(success, text);
}
```

This way you will have a loop for each IP that will continue independently of each other until `run` is set to `false`.

Comment: Thank you very much Manfred! Just 1 question:
Does this mean that the app will not start a new while loop until ALL pings receive answers?

Comment: @DementyYakovliev That is correct. Was that not the intended behavior? You could of course instead create a separate loop for **each IP**.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I wonder if there is any way to avoid the situation when one of replies is coming back for too long and we need to wait several seconds before starting another while loop. Just don't want to block all pings by one of them waiting for reply for too long.

Comment: Absolutely. I've noticed that you don't use the async ping methods so I'll write something up for that too - might be a moment.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I appreciate!

Comment: @DementyYakovliev Done :)

Comment: @DementyYakovliev Glad I could help. If this answers your question, please click the checkmark at the top-left of my answer to mark the question as answered. Upvotes are of course good too :)

Comment: That's ok, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

**Thread.Sleep(n)** blocks the current thread for n milliseconds. If I understand the code correctly it executes **action2** then suspends the *calling* thread for one second. If that thread *is* the main (UI) thread, your UI will be blocked.

Maybe moving the *while* loop to yet another thread would fix the problem.